# Frameworks for decoding image files

Tags: c++, c, image, frameworks, codec

I need some framework/library/codec pack for decoding image files of various formats (like DirectShow or libvlc for audio/video). I would prefer portable open source C/C++ project. What would you advise?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with OpenCv 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html